# Python: Array vs Database for storage of key/value

Tags: python, database, arrays, performance, postgresql

Q: Which is quicker for this scenario?

My scenario: my application will be storing either in either an array or postgresql db a list of links, so it might look like:

```
1) mysite.com
   a)    /users/login
   b)    /users/registration/
   c)    /contact/
   d)    /locate/search
   e)    /priv/admin-login
```

The above entries under `1)` - I will be doing `string` searches on these urls to find for example any path that contains:

```
'login'
```

for example.

The above letters a) through e) could maybe have anywhere from 5-100 more entries for a given domain.

**The usage: ** This data structure can change potentially as much as everyday, but only once per day. Some key/values will be removed, others will be modified. An individual set like:

```
dict2 = { 'thesite.com': 123, 98.6: 37 };
```

Each `key` will represent 1 and only 1 domain.

I've tried searching a bit on this, but cannot seem to find a real good answer to : when should an `array` be used and when should a db like `postgresql` be used?

I've always used a db to handle data (using mysql, not postgresql), but I'm now trying to do it better from now on, so I wondered if an array or other data structure would work better within a loop, and while trying tomatch a given string while looping.

As always, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "array"? Do you mean python dictionaries? Those are the typical way to store key/value-mappings. There are also arrays in Python, but they are probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you mean 'list' where you say 'array'.

Comment: Probably python dictionaries .

Comment: Looks like you're trying to develop a routing module for URLs?

Comment: We need to know more about usage. How many sites do you have? Do they change over time? Do you need to store them persistently? Do you use an application container like uwsgi?

Comment: @RickyA - Please see update information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full SQL database would probably be overkill. If you can fit everything in memory, put it all in a dict and then use the `pickle` module to serialize it and write it to the disk.

Another good option would be to use one of the dbm modules (`dbm`/`dbm.ndbm`, `gdbm` or `anydbm`) to store the data in a disk-bound hash table. It will have O(1) lookup times without the need to connect and form a query like in a bigger database.

edit: If you have multiple values per key and you don't want a full-blown database, SQLite would be a good choice. There is already a built-in module for it, `sqlite3` (as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: Depends on nr of sites and if he uses this script on multiple boxes.

Comment: This is a superb answer. Thanks for choosing a side. I think your point is well taken especially with the last sentence. Thank you!

Comment: sqlite is a great tiny database, and supports many sql features

Comment: Yes, sqlite could also be a good option. Then again, if you only have key/value pairs, even that can be overkill.

Comment: Would a SQLLite Db be good, if the key has multiple values like: [keyhere] value value value. Essentially a 1:M relationship between key/value ?

Comment: Yes, in fact it would be better. DBM databases are specifically key/value. You would have to jump through some hoops to get multiple values per key...not impossible, but not straight-forward. So yeah, SQLite is probably your best choice. I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Test it. It's your dataset, your hardware, your available disk and network IO, your usage pattern. There's no one true answer here. We don't even know how many queries are you planning - are we talking about one per minute or thousands per second?
2. If your data fits nicely in memory and doesn't take a massive amount of time to load the first time, sticking it into a dictionary in memory will probably be faster.
3. If you're always looking for full words (like in the `login` case), you will gain some speed too from splitting the url into parts and indexing those separately.

Comment: Great points here, especially #3. The whole point of asking the question though - was to say based on this information is it possible to rule out a dictionary or the use of a SQL db . I know I can always test (and I will), but I wondered if there was a glaringly obvious choice or not. Appreciate the comments here ! Thanks